# I can't run minio as a brew service

Tags: homebrew, minio

I trying to run `minio` as a *daemon* using `brew services`:

```bash
brew services start minio
```

And I get the following error

```
Error: Formula `minio` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file
```

I installed `minio` using `brew install minio/stable/minio` as specified in [the documentation for MacOS](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/quickstart/macos.html), and running `minio` as a one of command works

```bash
minio server ./data
```

Comment: Yup, same issue here. Did you ever solve this one?

Comment: @fractious nope. Ended up using docker to run minio. Which was slower and more of a hassle than just have a service running with brew…

Comment: Thanks. Yeah same, I'm using the docker image now.

Comment: I've raised an issue on the Github repo about this - https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/16382